# Discriminant of ideal equals its norm squared times the discriminant of the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

On p. 88 of Don Zagier's $\textit{Zetafunktionen und quadratische Körper}$, he defines the discriminant of an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}$ in the ring of integers of a quadratic number field, as $D(\mathfrak{a})=\textrm{det} \left(\begin{matrix}\alpha & \beta\\ \alpha' & \beta'\end{matrix} \right)^2$, where $\{\alpha, \beta \}$ is some $\mathbb{Z}$ basis for $\mathfrak{a}$.

He then makes the claim that

> $$D(\mathfrak{a})=N(\mathfrak{a})^2 D$$

where $D$ denotes the discriminant of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, so that we have either $D=4d$ or $D=d$ depending on the congruence relations of $d\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$, and $N(\mathfrak{a}):= [\mathcal{O} : \mathfrak{a}] = \lvert \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a} \rvert$ is the index of $\mathfrak{a}$ in $\mathcal{O}$.

He does not prove this but leaves it as an exercise.

The equality clearly holds for principal ideals, but I am stuck trying to prove it for non-principal ones.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$O = \Bbb{Z}+\tau \Bbb{Z}, \qquad Disc(O) = \det(\pmatrix{1 & \tau\\ 1 & \tau'}^\top\pmatrix{1 & \tau\\ 1 & \tau'})= \det(\pmatrix{1 & \tau\\ 1 & \tau'})^2$$
it is an integer because the middle matrix has entries $Tr(b_ib_j)\in \Bbb{Z}$.

For a **lattice** $$L = (a+b \tau)\Bbb{Z}+(c+d\tau)\Bbb{Z}\subset O$$
$$Disc(L) = \det(\pmatrix{a+b\tau & c+d\tau\\ a+b\tau' & c+d\tau'})^2=\det(\pmatrix{1 & \tau\\ 1 & \tau'}\pmatrix{a & c\\ b & d})^2$$

$$O/L\cong \pmatrix{1 & \tau\\ 1 & \tau'}\Bbb{Z}^2/\pmatrix{a+b\tau & c+d\tau\\ a+b\tau' & c+d\tau'}\Bbb{Z}^2 \cong \Bbb{Z}^2/\pmatrix{a & c\\ b & d}\Bbb{Z}^2$$ $$|O/L| = |\Bbb{Z}^2/\pmatrix{a & c\\ b & d}\Bbb{Z}^2|=|\det(\pmatrix{a & c\\ b & d})|$$

> ie. $$Disc(L) =Disc(O) |O/L|^2$$

Of course it works the same way in arbitrary number fields.