# Proposition 2.12 from Neukirch ANT. Notation question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, modules, algebraic-number-theory

What does the outlined index mean? Field notation has a similar notation in his book, only with square brackets.[image]

Comment: $\mathfrak{a}'$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ are abelian groups, so it's just the index of the subgroup $\mathfrak{a}$ inside $\mathfrak{a}'$. Equivalently, it's the cardinality of the $\mathcal{O}_K$-module $\mathfrak{a}'/\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: I just wrote a [proof about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3497677/276986), the idea is that we are looking at lattices $A\Bbb{Z}^n,AB\Bbb{Z}^n$